# How to override the javadoc for a final method in a sub class?

Tags: java, javadoc

```
public class BaseClass {
    /**
     * Gets the value.
     */
    public final String getValue() {
        // returns something.
    }
}

public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    /**
     * Gets the value.
     * <p/>
     * The value is meaningless for SubClass.
     */
    @Override // Cannot override final method
    public final String getValue() {
        super.getValue(); // Not overriding implementation, just javadoc
    }
}
```

I do not need to change the implementation of the final method, I just want to change the Javadoc for it.

Comment: *"The value is meaningless for SubClass."* This tells us the subclass shouldn't be a subclass, as it fails the "is a" test. If the value is meaningful to `BaseClass`, it should be meaningful for `SubClass`, as `SubClass` is meant to be a `BaseClass` (plus). Code written for `BaseClass`, which may well expect `value` to be meaningful, should work with `SubClass`. Perhaps you want composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Well ... you can't. Why not simply put the explanation into the class' documentation?

Comment: Your question make no sense. You can't override the method, so why would you want to override its documentation?

Comment: Fyi: I reworded the question title a bit - there is no need to mention the programming language again (that is what tags are for!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, there are times that we are subclassing an API class, but we want to be a little hackish, and it causes something from the original class to become useless. Of course, under normal ideal programming practice, this shouldn't happen or is, at least not recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply spoken: you can't do that. If at all, you could put some javadoc at the definition of that child class explaining that the behavior of that one final method has been changed. And if you can do that - you could change the javadoc on the **base** class to say: "sub classes might invalidate this method" or something alike.

Beyond that, you should understand that this is also a *questionable* idea conception wise.

Inheritance is not primarily about **code reuse**. It is about expressing that some class A **is-a** B, because A extends B. So when you decide to make a method *meaningless* on a subclass, you are basically invalidating the contract of the super class. And that is simply not good practice (see the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for why you have to be careful when *modifying* the contract of inherited methods).

You see, that keyword *final* is not only information to the compiler. It also expresses **intent** by the person who used it for that very method. This person said: "I don't want that subclasses *temper* with this method!"

Comment: Especially if the method is declared to be "final" it means that no sub class shall mess around with it by overloading it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not foreseen by Java, hence it is not possible to do using standard Java tools. You mya provide a more detailed explanation on the class level though.

You can also try to look at Javadoc API (Doclet API) and search for some custom implementations of it or implement your own extension, e.g. introduce new annotation on the class level, and implement custom Javadoc generator to respect those. I'm not aware if something like this already exists though.

Update:
Also see the [GhostCat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141618/how-to-override-the-javadoc-for-a-final-method-in-a-sub-class/45141749#45141749), he has a bunch of reasons why you should not do that.